# How to return void* from function?

Tags: c++

I am trying to

- get `void*` from a method for `int`
- pass that pointer to another  method and get back the int value.

When I am doing this directly, like passing &x  to the conversion method it returns correct value, but through method call I am getting weird number.

here is the code...

```
void *GetVoidPointer(int a)
{   
    return &a;
}

int ReadValueFromVoidPointer(void *ptr)
{   
    int *i = static_cast<int*>(ptr);
    return *i;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 10;

    //Through method call to get void* : This doesn't work
    int i= ReadValueFromVoidPointer(GetVoidPointer(x));
    printf("%d\n", i);

    //Direct call  : This works
    int y= ReadValueFromVoidPointer(&x);
    printf("%d\n", y);

    return 0;
}
```

I am very new to C++ so might be doing something very silly. Please advise.

Comment: In `GetVoidPointer()`, `a` is a *local variable* that is a *copy* of whatever value the caller passed in. You are returning the address of that local variable. That address is no longer valid as soon as `GetVoidPointer()` exits, thus it is not safe to use in `ReadValueFromVoidPointer()`.

Comment: Would `void* GetVoidPointer(int& a)` help here? This is a really strange thing to do in a function since `static_cast` is the tool for the job both for converting and de-converting and it doesn't need a wrapper. That just overly complicates what should be simple.

Comment: Yes, although it's a lot of effort to write a function that simply provides `&x`.

Comment: It will work if you change the prototype of the GetVoidPointer function to void *GetVoidPointer(int &a)

Comment: thanks, every one. I get the point, coming from VBA where (byref/byval) are not  that important, I see what's I am doing wrong.  Thanks again.

Comment: You should not do such things in C++ unless you have to communicate to C API or something similar.

Answer (score 4):

When compiling your code you receive the following error :

```
test.cpp: In function ‘void* GetVoidPointer(int)’:
test.cpp:4:26: warning: address of local variable ‘a’ returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]
 void *GetVoidPointer(int a)
```

It means that your are returning the adress of a local variable (`a`), which is a problem as this variable is removed at the end of the function call.
Therefore you have to pass a `reference` to it (I'll let you look for some detailed explanations about it...).
So you just have to change the `GetVoidPointer()` by the following and everything is OK : `void *GetVoidPointer(int& a)`.
The result values are `10` and `10`.
I'm using the compile `g++` in version `8.3.0` with no added options.

Answer (score 0):

In function GetVoidPointer, the local param 'a' is temporary. When GetVoidPointer returned, 'a' will be destroyed by the system. So, you will not get the correct value. You could use 'C++ reference'.

Comment: `a` is not a temporary, you should be more careful with terminology, "temporary" has particular meaning in C++.